# CO$_2$ in photorespiration

Tags: bioenergetics

"Photorespiration is wasteful to plants as it reduces the amount of CO$_2$ available for fixation" my textbook says.

But we also know that photorespiration takes place when the concentration of CO$_2$ falls within the leaves. But CO$_2$ is also released in photorespiration. Why can't the CO$_2$ released here be fixed by RuBisCO?

Comment: Could you please give a complete citation from your text book and identify it by name, title, and publication date. That way we can cross-check it. You will be aware that posters on this site need to demonstrate that they have tried to answer this question themselves, but haven't done so. Have you searched this site for other questions on "photorespiration"? If not do so, and in any case tell us why what you found does not answer your question.